# How can I set up muti-booting via GRUB on a USB with a different OS?

Tags: boot, grub2, usb

How can I set up multi-booting with GRUB on a USB with a different OS? I want to choose the different OS when I plug in the USB.

Comment: This is handled by your bios, set your bios boot order to boot the USB > hard drive.

Comment: If you have grub.cfg on your flash drive you can add as many boot stanza. If from a full install you add entries to 40_custom. If just a grub only boot flash drive you do directly edit grub.cfg (exception to rule that we do not directly edit grub.cfg) https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MaintenanceFreeCustomGrub2Screen And. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/CustomMenus You can also chain load to MBR on internal drive if desired.

Comment: Thank you.  oldfred. One more question => When I change my bios boot order and plug in the USB, I need to change the grub.cfg and /etc/fstab each time because the origin /dev/sda changed into /dev/sdb. How to deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

1. YUMI – Multiboot USB Creator
2. XBOOT – Multiboot ISO USB Creator (Windows)
3. SARDU – Multiboot USB Creator (Windows)

http://www.pendrivelinux.com/multiboot-create-a-multiboot-usb-from-linux/

Comment: Dear BallWarapol, Thank a lot. I will like to try it and share my experience.